# Лого форума на движке XenForo 1.5.13

Tags: css, forum

Как сделать так чтобы лого у всег отображалось одинаково. Чтобы оно автоматический растягивалось и не размывалось, как буд-то делаешь это в фотошопе. У всех расширения мониторов разные... Вот так сейчас выглядит...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для начала надо сделать подготовить в графическом редакторе изображение в высоком разрешении (с учетом плотности пикселей). Далее указываем в соответствующем классе изображения `width: 100%; height: auto;`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59796/discussion-on-answer-by-dmitry-maslennikov-----xenforo-1-5-13).